# Show / hide same div id with jquery

Tags: jquery

My question is simple to explain but hard (for me) to solve
One link must hide (or toggle) several  with same id

```
<div class="buttons">
<a  id="showall">All</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Morning</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">APM</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Night</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2a</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2b</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
```

In this example

```
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">APM</a>
```

should display

```
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2a</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2b</div>
```

with this jQuery

```
jQuery(function(){
         jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
               jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
        });
        jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
              jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
              jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
        });
});
```

[JS Fiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/3562/)

Comment: `ID` **must be unique** for every element. Use `classes` instead.

Comment: Why do you do jQuery() for all of them?

Comment: @Shahar: Another library may also be using `$`.

Comment: Works fine if you use classes instead of misuse IDs: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XwN2L/3563/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use rel instead of id

http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/3564/

```
$(function(){
         $('#showall').click(function(){
               jQuery('.targetDiv').show();
        });
        $('.showSingle').click(function(){
              var self = $(this);
              $('.targetDiv').hide();
              $('.targetDiv[rel=div' + self.attr('target') +']').show();
        });
});
```

HTML

```
<div rel="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div rel="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2a</div>
<div rel="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2b</div>
<div rel="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
```

or you can even use classes, the issue is you have multiple ID with the same name. ID must be unique

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use class instead of multiple ids as already mentioned in the comments. Still there is an alternative to do it. Try this to select all the elements with same ids.

```
$('div[id="div2"]')
```

It will give you 2 divs as expected. Here is the [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/tajihuce/1/edit?html,js,console)

PS: I am posting this answer just to help other people with an alternative. I do not intend to encourage using bad practices in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<style>
div[class]{display:none;}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.showSingle').click(function(){
        $('div[class]').hide()
        var id=$(this).attr('target')
        $('.div'+id).show()
        })
    $('#showall').click(function(){
        $('div[class]').show()
        })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="buttons">
<a  id="showall">All</a><br/>
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Morning</a><br/>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">APM</a><br/>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Night</a><br/>
</div>

<div class="div1">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div class="div2">Lorum Ipsum2a</div>
<div class="div2">Lorum Ipsum2b</div>
<div class="div3">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
</body>
</html>
```